# What is the difference between < and << in C?

Tags: c, comparison, comparison-operators

I was writing a C code for an assignment in school and came across an error that really stumped me. Below is the code snippet that was causing issues.

```
int i, result = 1;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(a[i]<< 15 || a[i] >> 50)
        result = 0;
}
```

Every time that I tried to run my program, I would see a warning that 50 was too large for my data type. Knowing that I was using an int type and that the number 50 can easily be stored in an int I assumed that it was expecting a value less than 32 since int is a 32-byte type. I tried using the number 20 instead of 50 and got no errors. I then replaced the double "<" and ">" marks with singles and the code worked perfectly. I was wondering if anybody could shed some light on why this was the case? I am new to C and just took a shot in the dark that the extra "<" and ">" symbols were the issue, but I would love to know why it worked!

Comment: The actual question is why would you try to compare with >> or << in the first place. But you can look up operators in C in any book or tutorial and see what they do in a second.

Answer (score 0):

">" and "<" are relational operators where as ">>" and "<<" are bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

**Relational** operators in C:

==, >, **<**, >=, <=, !=

**Bitwise** operators in C:

&, ~, ^, **<<**, >>, |

For detailed info: 
[Relational operators in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_relational_operators.htm)
[Bitwise operators in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm)

In the given program, a[i] << 15 will left shift the binary value a[i] and similiarly a[i]>>50 will do  50 Right shift of the binary value of a[i].

As written above, >> and << are bitwise operators not relational operators.

Hope it helps!!